# Suppose $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$. Show that $\min\{x_n, y_n\} \rightarrow \min\{x, y\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, maxima-minima

> Suppose $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$. Show that $\min\{x_n, y_n\} \rightarrow \min\{x, y\}$

I'm not really sure how to *show* this. If $x_n$ converges to $x$ and $y_n$ converges to $y$, then wouldn't it already trivially follow that $\min\{x_n, y_n\}$ converges to  $\min\{x, y\}$?

I know that I'm missing something, and any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not trivial at all. Consider separately the three cases $x<y$,  $x=y$ , $x>y$.

Comment: @Crostul well in each of the cases the min would be x, x or y, and y respectively, but where does the convergence come in? The reason I currently see it as trivial is because with the way I'm conceptualizing it right now $x_n$ and $x$ and $y_n$ and $y$ are practically interchangeable so the min will always be the same in all those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a nice statement about the min, and you are done.

> Lemma : $\min\{ a,b\} = \dfrac{a+b - |a-b|}{2}$.

Proof : If $a \geq b$, then $|a-b| = a-b$, so that $a+b-a+b = 2b$. Otherwise, $a < b$, so $|a-b| = b-a$, and we have $a+b + a - b = 2a$. After division by $2$, we see this corresponds to the minimum function.

Note that $|\min\{x_n,y_n\} -\min\{x,y\}|= \left|\frac{(x_n + y_n - |x_n - y_n|) - (x + y - |x-y|)}2 \right|$.

We use triangle inequality:
$$
\left|\frac{(x_n + y_n - |x_n - y_n|) - (x + y - |x-y|)}2 \right| \leq \left|\frac{x_n-x}2\right| + \left|\frac{y_n-y}2\right| + \left|\frac{|x_n-y_n| - |x-y|}2\right|
$$

Observe the terms on the right hand side. The first can be made small, since $x_n \to x$. The second can be made small, since $y_n \to y$. The third canbe made small, since $x_n - y_n \to  x-y$.

Hence, we have convergence.

Inductively, I encourage you to show this corollary:

> For any finite of number of convergent sequences $s_1...s_n$, $\min_{1 \leq i \leq n}\{s_i\} $ will converge to the minimum of the limits.

Alternately, you can also show  this for maximum, because for the maximum of two quantities, there is a similar formula:
$$
\max\{a,b\}  = \frac{a + b + |a-b|}{2}
$$

Hence, the same argument will follow.

Answer (score 3):

We have that
$$
\min\{x_n,y_n\}=\frac{x_n+y_n-|x_y-y_n|}2.
$$
Using the properties of limits and the continuity of the absolute value, we get
$$
\frac{x_n+y_n-|x_y-y_n|}2\to\frac{x+y-|x-y|}2=\min\{x,y\}
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Which properties of limits?

Comment: @abc We need to use the facts that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n \pm b_n) =  \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \pm \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} c a_n =  c \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$.